# How do I get slider to go to specific position on tap on ipad. HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, webkit

On safari desktop the slider one can click with the mouse to go to specific position on the slider. For instance you can click to go to the end. On the ipad you have to drag it the round ball with your finger to move the position of the slider.  I would like on an ipad to be able to tap to get it to a specific position like on the desktop.

The code I'm using for the slider is

```
<input id = "slider" type="range" min="0" max="45" step="1" value="0" OnChange = "Slider();">
```

I would like to avoid using jquery but if I have to I will use jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked for something not JQuery, but you should see how well the slider works. Also to note, an input of type range is not compatible with IE9 and below.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uRWy/1/)

```
$("#slider ").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 45,
    step:1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: OK thanks going to try this out today. Luckily I only need to support iPad.

Comment: I've tried this solution and I keep getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'. I know this is the solution I'm looking for because I went to the website on the ipad and works exactly the way I want it to.

Comment: Make sure that you include jQuery and jQuery UI, and that should solve your problems.